# como fazer um gerador de senhas sem usar vários loops?

Tags: python

Como podem ver o programa abaixo "gera" diversas sequências de caracteres únicas. A intenção aqui não é criar um algoritmo especifico pra isso, se trata apenas de um exemplo. O estudo do caso é sobre formas de reduzir a quantidade de loops aninhados nesse tipo de ocasião.
Para propósitos gerais segue o código:

```
char = [chr(i) for i in range(33, 123)]

for one in char: 
    for two in char: 
        for three in char: 
            for four in char: 
                for five in char: 
                    for six in char: 
                        for seven in char: 
                            for eight in char: 
                                for nine in char: 
                                    print(one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
```

Comment: Pesquise sobre o módulo `itertools`

Comment: Tive que executar para entende que é um algorítimo de força bruta para quebrar senhas.

Answer (score 1):

Não seria o caso de usar uma função recursiva?

```
char = [chr(i) for i in range(33, 123)]

#print(char) tinha usado essa linha num teste e esqueci de tirar

def attk(senha, n):
  if (n > 0):
    for item in char: 
       attk(senha + item, n - 1)
  else:   
    print(senha)      


attk("", 9)
```

Código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/MoccasinMutedMonads)

Comment: Desculpe, mas porque o fui negativado?

Comment: É a vida Augusto. Tem pessoas aqui que dão negativo por qualquer razão kkkk #Sad ;-;. Enfim, uma coisa que você pode colocar na sua resposta é o uso da função itertools.product. Creio que seja a forma mais simples e a melhor para gerar várias combinações.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002, se a pessoa negativou porque não usei o `itertools.product` ela não levou em conta que o `itertools` não consegue fazer esse produto para nove dígitos. Com quatro casas ele já dá erro OUT_OF_MEMORY e encerra o processo. De uma olhada https://repl.it/repls/JumboSlimFirm

Comment: @JeanExtreme002, obrigado pela observação.

Comment: Que estranho. Eu utilizo o itertools.product com mais de 4 casas com meu interpretador e ele não me dá esse erro '-'.  Edit: Testei tirar o list() e ele funcionou . Sabe o porquê ? https://repl.it/repls/LiveDelightfulSystemsanalysis

Comment: Consumiu a memória porque o bobão aqui fez `list( product(char, repeat=4))`, forçando o itertools a consumir toda a RAM em uma lista com todos os resultados. Vacilo meu.

Comment: Então né.... 50 conto por corrigir seu erro kkk